# How to select top 1 based on 3 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CarID    Date             Shift
1        2016-08-20       3
1        2016-08-21       1
1        2016-08-21       2
2        2016-08-20       1
3        2016-08-21       3
```

---

Expected Result

```
CarID    Date             Shift
1        2016-08-21       2
2        2016-08-20       1
3        2016-08-21       3
```

How to write such query to get the top 1 record of every car with the combination of max date and max shift?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the ranking function `ROW_NUMBER`, for example in a CTE:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CarID ORDER BY Date DESC, Shift DESC), *
   FROM dbo.TableName t
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want max value of Date and Shift that are in the same row:

```
   select top 1 with ties CarId, [Date], Shift
     from myTable
    order by row_number() over (partition by CarId order by [Date] desc, Shift desc);
```

Comment: Undervalued answer!

Comment: @gofr1 Thanks, surprised to see that much difference on punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

Another way with OUTER APPLY:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.*
FROM YourTable a
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE CarID=a.CarID
    ORDER BY [Date] DESC, [Shift] DESC) as b
```

Output:

```
CarID   Date        Shift
1       2016-08-21  2
2       2016-08-20  1
3       2016-08-21  3
```